# Use variable to call out sheet and get TypeError: Cannot call method "copyTo" of undefined. Details

Tags: google-apps-script

I was trying to use a script to copy the active sheet so then I could duplicate some protections.  The total script works great if I just put in the sheet name as text manually in line three rather than using the variable ActiveSheetName

If I use this code it works fine I don't get the error so I assume it has something to do with the variable ActiveSheetName not being a text string or something but I can't figure out how to make it work

```
'var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); '
'sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');'
'sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('My Copy');'
```

If I use the the code below I get a TypeError: Cannot call method "copyTo" of undefined.

```
'var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();' 
'var ActiveSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();'
'sheet = ss.ActiveSheetName;'
'sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('My Copy');'
```

Comment: Try `sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ActiveSheetName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getSheetByName(yourSheetName)` method with your variable as an argument, as `Spreadsheet` is not a simple js `Object` (besides, in order to use es6 variable property name it should be accessed via bracket syntax `object[propertyName]`)

Comment: Thank you but if I'm reading what you are saying properly I would need to manually put in the sheet name in the "yourSheetName" field. The issue with that is I have a copy button in the worksheet that calls this script. Then after it copies that sheet I want to be able to hit the button in the copied sheet (which has a different name) to call the same script and copy that one.  This is why I was trying to get it to return the name of the active sheet where I hit the copy button as a variable.

Comment: ? All I am saying is that *after* accessing your sheet name with `getActiveSheet().getName()`, instead of referencing `Sheet` by `ss.yourVariableName` you should access it via `ss.getSheetByName(ActiveSheetName)`... What you are doing now is trying to find what is written into `ActiveSheetName` property, thus the `undefined` result, as there is no property *named* `ActiveSheetName`

Comment: Ahh I see Thank you

Comment: No problem! :) If you are new to apps script, take a look at the [apps script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/), most of the classes that are offered through the services such as `SpreadsheetApp` behave a bit differently than your usual `Objects`